# Pointer to arrays

Tags: c++

Could anyone tell me why the second and the last receive compile-time errors?

```
void test(){
    
    int array[10]{};

    int (*i) [10] = &array; // works
    int (*j) [10] = array;  // does not work
    int *k = array;     // works
    int *l = new int[10](); // works
    int (*m) [10] = new int[10]();      // does not work

    exit(0);
}
```

I'm not sure why the second does not work without the ampersand since array and &array refer to the same address. For the last, I think it's because it can't tell we're dynamically allocating an array specifically, but I'd like this confirmed.

Comment: I think you are trying to learn "C" style arrays (legacy style in my opinion). Pointers to arrays are not really the thing you should use in C++ anyway. Use std::array for arrays with fixed size. Use std::vector for arrays that need to be resizable. If you want a pointer to data in a std::array or vector, use their data() methods. E.g. a dynamically allocated array in C++ should look like this : `std::vector<int> values(10);`

Comment: `array` (after decay to pointer) and `&array` have the same numerical value, but different types: `int *` vs `int (*)[10]`. And the last line doesn't work because `new`ing an array is a special case, and returns a pointer to first element instead of a pointer to the whole array.

Comment: `array` decays to `int*` not `int (*)[10]`. Also **even though the address value is same there type is different**. That is `array` and `&array` value is same but type is different.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The irony here is that most people saying *"avoid C feature"* know them themselves. You'll have to learn them sooner or later, even if you know to avoid them in everyday programming.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes I agree, but the other irony is that most educational materials still start with "C" style arrays (and new and delete).  And that should change too.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - Perhaps we are just a bit sad that beginners waste their time on this? Shouldn't "Here be dragons" be enough, or do they always have to ask "But *how* hot is the dragon breath?". Learning this "Sooner or later" should preferrably be "later".

Comment: `array` does not refer to an address, it refers to an array. The third is equivalent to `int *k = &array[0];` – `k` does not point to the array but to  its first element. `&array` and `&array[0]` are the same location because there is nothing in front of the first element in the array, but they are not the same type of thing. (Consider the difference between "the person standing at the front of the queue" and "the queue that starts where that person is standing".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm not sure why the second does not work without the ampersand since array and &array refer to the same address.
> `int (*j) [10] = array;`

`array` decays to `int*` not `int (*)[10]` in several contexts. So **even though the value of `array` and `&array` is same the types are different**. The type of `array` before decaying is `int [10]` which decays to `int*` while the type of `&array` is `int (*)[10]`.

So the error is telling you that we cannot initialize a `int(*)[10]`(type on the left hand side) with an `int*`(type on the right hand side after decay).

```
error: cannot convert ‘int*’ to ‘int (*)[10]’ in initialization
```

---

Similarly in the last case `int (*m) [10] = new int[10]()` the type on the right hand side is `int*` which cannot be used to intialize the type on the left hand side(`int (*)[10]`).